# Why Carrie didn't kill gym teacher in 2013 movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, reference, carrie-2013

I saw the 1976 version of [**Carrie**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074285/) where she killed the gym teacher at the prom,

However, in [**2013 version**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1939659/) she didn't.

Why was this change made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrie spared the gym teacher because she felt compassion for her, even if she was slapped (that was to snap her out to focus, most likely). Personally, I think it would be *unreasonable* for Carrie to kill her though.